# How to set ImageButton property of app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic" programmatically?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-imagebutton

How to set the `ImageButton` property of

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic"
```

programmatically?

Something like `myImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.eng2);` but the property of `app:srcCompat`.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You need to use [setImageResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html?utm_campaign=android_launch_supportlibrary23.2_022216&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#setImageResource(int)) method.

`imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.eng2);`

Comment: Same for Kotlin

Comment: does that mean that we dont use srcCompat changes on xml?

Answer (score 26):

First, ensure you are dealing with `AppCompatImageView`, not regular  `ImageView`:

```
AppCompatImageView iv = (AppCompatImageView)findViewById(....);
```

and then you can do:

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic);
```

See other public methods [in docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html).

Comment: I'm using 'ImageButton' with 'app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic"' but setting to 'setImageResource(R.drawable.pic);' works fine. Thank you

Comment: build tools are probably replacing classes "in fly"

Comment: hey Marcin, do you know why we need to programmatically change the image instead of giving the path between app:srcCompa="drawable/"

Comment: I want to add to this answer, I had to use `AppCompatImageButton` instead of `ImageButton`.

Comment: @Zhang That probably because you the activity where the view was inflated didn't extend AppCompatActivity

Comment: @AndreRomano no, my subview was created inside a class which extends relative layout.

Answer (score 3):

Using `setImageResource()` should fetch its resource in a backwards-compatible manner without any further effort required.

However if you are using `setImageDrawable()`, the ImageView/ImageButton will not help with any backwards compat and it's up to you to supply a backward-compat drawable, which is important for eg. if using `VectorDrawables`.  The following will load and set a drawable in such a way:

```
val drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, resourceId)
image.setImageDrawable(drawable)
```

Comment: For ImageButtons, its working

Answer (score 1):

None, of the provided solutions worked for me. I was using an ImageView. Finally, I found out that using `setBackgroundResource()` works for me.

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_star_black_18dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess other methods are outdated and wouldn't work at the time of writing this,

```
iv_yourImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable));
```

This will work.